# how to configure pycharm so that it will work with kaggle kernel python notebook?

Tags: pycharm, kaggle

I am using the latest version of pycharm, `pychram pro 2.19.1.2`. This version is supposed to have jupyter notebook support.  I have some personal kernels on kaggle and I want to know how I can edit my kernel directly from pycharm IDE rather than upload from my PC with upload notebook each time I want to run my code in the kernel. I've tried to configure jupyter srever with the kernel link like in the picture

[image]

Comment: Same question, do you have own answer?